# Python/MatPlotLib yield odd, unexpected contours

Tags: python, matplotlib, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to contour plot a function that's 0 at the 4 vertices of 
the unit square, and 1 in the middle of that square. I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot 
z = [[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,0], [.5,.5,1]] 
cn = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(z) 
matplotlib.pyplot.show(cn)
```

And got this:

[image]

I expected a series of concentric squares, like this:

[image]

which is what I get when I do

```
ListContourPlot[{{0,0,0}, {1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {1,1,0}, {.5,.5,1}}, 
ColorFunction -> (Hue[#1]&)]
```

in Mathematica.

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: I realize there's more than one way to draw contours for given data. In this case, a series of concentric circles would also have been fine.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd expect concentric rings with the array you're plotting. If you want one in the middle and zeros at the corner then surely you want something more like this: `z = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For non-meshed data, as suggested in the comments, you probably want to use the tricontour function:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> z = [[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,0], [.5,.5,1]] 
>>> x, y, z = zip(*z)
>>> cn = plt.tricontourf(x, y, z)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: output]

HTH

Comment: Thanks! I'm approving this answer because I'm sure it would 
work. Unfortunately, my matplotlib doesn't have the tricontourf() 
function. I tried to upgrade to matplotlib 1.3.0, but this requires 
and numpy 1.5, and my attempt to upgrade numpy failed with a linker 
error. 

While I'm sure I could get this working eventually, I'm going to 
pursue an approach using qhull.

Actually, it looks like scipy uses qhull for some of the work it does anyway, so using qhull directly should hopefully work.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because the expected inputs *are entirely different*

[mathematica `ContourListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListContourPlot.html) expects (the way you are calling it) a list of points of the form `{x, y, z}`.

In [matplotlib `contour`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour) (the way you are calling it) expects an array of `z` values.

Given your input, it is generating the correct contours. To see this clearly look at `imshow(z)`.

Comment: So the z values it's expecting would apply to a mesh of x and y values that I'd supplied earlier? Does this mean, I can't give it arbitrary (non-meshed) x,y,z triplets without using something like interpolate?

Comment: Triplets aren't allowed, if you want to contour non-meshed data you're probably looking for the extensive tri-* routines in mpl. tricontour being one of them. HTH